# Overwriting an existing golang structure and adding a field

Tags: go, apache-kafka

```
    func (c *client) Init(conf config.Config, topic string) (err error) {
    defer func() {
        p := recover()
        switch v := p.(type) {
        case error:
            err = v
        }
    }()
    c.reader = kafka.NewReader(kafka.ReaderConfig{
        Brokers:               conf.Brokers,
        GroupID:               conf.GroupID,
        Topic:                 topic,
        MaxWait:               1 * time.Second,    // maximum time to wait for new messages
        MinBytes:              1,                  // minimum message size
        MaxBytes:              10e6,               // maximum message size 1 MByte (= maximum size Kafka can handle)
        RetentionTime:         time.Hour * 24 * 7, // keep ConsumerGroup for 1 week
        WatchPartitionChanges: true,               // watch for changes to the partitions (e.g. increase of partitions)
    })
    if conf.TlsEnabled {
        d := &kafka.Dialer{
            TLS: &tls.Config{},
        }
    }
    return err
}
```

Long story short: what I wanna do is adding the field `Dialer:    d` to `c.reader` if TlsEnabled is true! c.reader is of type ReaderConfig which already contains Dialer field which is in my case:

```
    d := &kafka.Dialer{
    TLS: &tls.Config{},
    }
```

Comment: Why not assign the `ReaderConfig` to a temp variable, then check `conf.TlsEnabled`, if true set  `tmp.Dialer = &kafka.Dialer{}`, and _then_ have `c.reader = kafka.NewReader(tmp)`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I don't think its possible - `NewReader` returns an instance of https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/segmentio/kafka-go#Reader `Reader` which has only non-exported fields

Comment: @Inian yeah, read the question properly last time, `Dialer` is a field of `ReaderConfig`, not the return of `kafka.NewReader`. Still, you can simply create the `ReaderConfig`  object first, then check if you need to add `Dialer`, then call `NewReader`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to set the `Dialer` field on `kafka.ReaderConfig` if, and only if `conf.TlsEnabled` is true. In that case, you should just move your `if conf.TlsEnabled` check before you call `kafka.NewReader`, and assign the `kafka.ReaderConfig` to a variable, like so:

```
rConf := kafka.ReaderConfig{
    Brokers:               conf.Brokers,
    GroupID:               conf.GroupID,
    Topic:                 topic,
    MaxWait:               1 * time.Second,    // maximum time to wait for new messages
    MinBytes:              1,                  // minimum message size
    MaxBytes:              10e6,               // maximum message size 1 MByte (= maximum size Kafka can handle)
    RetentionTime:         time.Hour * 24 * 7, // keep ConsumerGroup for 1 week
    WatchPartitionChanges: true,               // watch for changes to the partitions (e.g. increase of partitions)
}
if conf.TlsEnabled {
    rConf.Dialer = &kafka.Dialer{
        TLS: &tls.Config{},
    }
}
// now assign c.reader
c.reader = kafka.NewReader(rConf)
```

Just a small nit-pick: in golang, acronyms and other initialisms should be in all-caps. Your config type should not have a field called `TlsEnabled`, but rather it should be `TLSEnabled`.

Comment: nitpick on nitpick - in _Go_ ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a field to an existing type but you can embed the `client` in a custom type.  The fields can then be accessed directly via the custom type

```
type myType struct {
    something string
    foo       int
    bar       int
}

type myExtendedType struct {
    myType
    dialer *kafka.Dialer
}

func main() {
    ext := myExtendedType{
        myType: myType{
            something: "some",
            foo:       24,
            bar:       42,
        },
        dialer: &kafka.Dialer{
            TLS: &tls.Config{},
        },
    }
    println(ext.something, ext.foo, ext.bar, ext.dialer)
}
```